# Failing to clone through Intellij - clone failed. Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea, rsa, jetbrains-ide

I have added a my rsa key to gitlab.
When I clone from git CLI it adds my target to the known host file in the git folder.

But I still can't work with the Git clone from Intellij (Check out from version control -> git)
I get

> "clone failed. Could not read from remote repository".

How can I work with git integration in intellij 16/15/14 (tried all versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following setting:

Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> SSH Executable

If it's set to Built-in switch to Native and give it a try.

Make sure you have the files id_rsa and id_rsa.pub stored in the correct location as well.